# xRecord.data method generates record with identical RecId

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I understand that the table's **data method creates a copy** of a record including the system fields. Normally it should generate a new RecID, which is reasonable because otherwise you cannot insert the record in the same table.

Now I'm having a case where the data method is creating a copy which has the **same RecId**, leading to an error during the insert operation. I'm not sure why this is happening and would appreciate any input on this topic.

What I'm doing:

- Duplicating an existing product configuration model
  [image: Screenshot]
- When I run the debugger, at some point the execution thread reaches a table method PCClass.duplicateTranslation()
  [image]
- In line 20 and 22 we can see that a duplicate record is created, which is then tried to insert, which fails because they have both the same RecId (see next screenshot)
  [image]

This is a standard AX method, so why isn't it working?

Comment: Probably a bug, they should not use the `data` method here. Try using `buf2buf` instead. As far as I know, a new `RecId` is only created if `RecId` is 0.

Comment: The use `data` is all okay, see `Docu::copy`. Some other index is involved.

Comment: @FH-Inway, I was thinking in the same direction and tried with buf2buf(). As you sayed, the RecID then is 0. Unfortunately my problem was not solved because the problem was caused by another index during insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data` method of table objects copies all fields including `RecId` and other system fields. The `insert` methods takes care of the generation of `RecId`.

By the above logic your code should not fail due to the `RecId` index.
Maybe another unique index is in play?
Most likely you passed a wrong or zero `RecId` in the call to the method.

You use two records buffer, this is unnecessary, just change the record key fields and insert:

```
while select translation 
    where translation.Category == this.RecId ...
{
    translation.Category = _duplicateComponent;
    translation.insert();
}
```

Comment: The problem is indeed coming from another index. So my assumption that the same RecId was causing the issue was wrong.